# CookieFirst API function and object not returning "null"

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I'm currently trying to get the CookieFirst API running to use this for my Google Tag Manager setup.

Therefore I want to check if the user has already given consent or is "new" and consent is not available in any form yet. According to the [API documentation](https://support.cookiefirst.com/hc/de/articles/360011568738-Javascript-API) that should work with `CookieFirst.consent;`. When using this in Chrome, I get `null` as result in the console.

So I wrote this little script to verify that:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("cf_consent", function(event) {
    var newlyGivenConsent = event.detail || CookieFirst.consent;
    console.log(newlyGivenConsent);
    if (newlyGivenConsent === undefined || newlyGivenConsent === null) {
        console.log('No Consent Yet')
    } else {
        console.log('Consent received');
    }
});
</script>
```

But somehow `console.log(newlyGivenConsent);` logs me `{necessary: true, functional: false, performance: false, advertising: false}` and not `null` as expected.

I'm pretty newish to JS so I can't manage to find a way to get this working.

Can someone help and explain what I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a bug in CookieFirst which caused triggering of `cf_consent` event with empty consent object (only necessary category accepted) on banner load. It has been resolved since.